# Plesk FTP not working but SFTP and Shell is working

Tags: linux, ftp, shell, sftp

I am facing a strange problem. The FTP on my Plesk VPS is not working. Whenever I try to connect, FileZilla FTP client says:

> Status: Resolving address of xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com
>   Status: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:21...
>   Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
>   **Error: Could not connect to server**

So, it's not even going to the step of asking username/password. So, it's something else.

---

The SFTP on port 22 is working fine. Also, I can successfully do shell access and run commands.

But, I **NEED** FTP access too on port 21. I have searched everywhere but can not find any setting to enable it. This is the Plesk version info:

> Parallels Plesk Panel version 9.5.2
>   Operating system Linux 2.6.26.8-57.fc8
>   CPU GenuineIntel, Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 CPU 3.00GHz

Any help is appreciated.

**[EDIT]:**

The firewall is not blocking it. I have checked it on server and there are absolutely no blocking rule. Firewall states:

> All incoming/outgoing connections are accepted on FTP

And on client-side (my PC), I can connect to other FTP servers so this is not an issue in my PC's firewall. Moreover, I can not even connect to the FTP from online FTP clients like [net2ftp](http://www.net2ftp.com/).

Comment: Sounds like the FTP server isn't started. But since I (willingly) know nothing of Plesk, that's all I can help with.

Comment: What version of linux are you using? Does the command "service --status-all" do anything for you?

Comment: If you have functional SFTP, why do you "need" regular FTP? It's an inferior protocol in every single aspect, both securitywise and in terms of efficiency.

Comment: If you have working SCP/SFTP - is it blocked for security purposes? FTP is garbage security. Only need anymore is for anonymous, maybe, possibly... Meh, no not even for that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your VPS provider doesn't want you to use FTP (it's not very secure after all...)?  Did you check their documentation and/or ask their support people about this?

Comment: I have got the root access and everything. I can enable that myself. Just want to know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I would check if FTP server is running at all. It could be also blocking rule on firewall
  --
Regards,
Robert

Comment: Firewall is not an issue. See my updated question. And **how do I check if FTP server is running or not?** What command should I issue on shell to check this. Please elaborate.

Comment: You can check the output of `netstat -tlp` run as root.

Comment: alternately, `ps axuf` and see if there's any running process with the phrase `ftpd` in it. Alternately, something named `inetd`, which would be your cue to check `/etc/inetd.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try restarting PLESK, which in CentOS for me is

```
/etc/init.d/psa restart
```

Then, try restarting the PLESK FTP service specifically

```
/etc/init.d/xinetd restart
```

And for laughs, Apache as well

```
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

I'd also update PLESK.